# repository_missing_exception snapshot and restore in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, snapshot

I have to transfer an Elasticsearch index on a Windows machine to an Ubuntu Machine. I decided to take a snapshot of the index and then try to restore it on the other system.

I was successfully able to snapshot the index on the windows machine.
On the windows machine in `elasticsearch.yml` I had `path.repo: ["F:\\mount\\backups"]`.

So, under `mount` I had:

```
.
└── backups
    └── old_backup
        ├── index
        ├── indices
        │   └── old_index
        │       ├── 0
        │       ├── 1
        │       ├── 2
        │       ├── 3
        │       ├── 4
        │       └── meta-snapshot_to_ubuntu.dat
        ├── meta-snapshot_to_ubuntu.dat
        └── snap-snapshot_to_ubuntu.dat
```

where `snapshot_to_ubuntu` is the name of the snapshot I made on Windows.

I placed this snapshot in `~/Documents/mount` on the ubuntu machine and start an instance of ES 2.3.0 with `path.repo: ["/home/animesh/Documents/mount/backups"]` in `elasticsearch.yml`.

I run the following on the command line:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_snapshot/old_backup/snapshot_to_ubuntu?pretty=1
```

and get

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "repository_missing_exception",
      "reason" : "[old_backup] missing"
    } ],
    "type" : "repository_missing_exception",
    "reason" : "[old_backup] missing"
  },
  "status" : 404
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE**:

I ran the following curl command:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/old_backup/snapshot_to_ubuntu/_restore
```

and I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "repository_missing_exception",
        "reason": "[old_backup] missing"
      }
    ],
    "type": "repository_missing_exception",
    "reason": "[old_backup] missing"
  },
  "status": 404
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue and I would like to share with you how I figured it out.
I will write all steps, hope it may helps other people as well.

I had to transfer an Elasticsearch index on a GCP server to my Local Machine. I decided to take a snapshot of the index and then try to restore it on my Local machine.

**I'm assuming you already have the snapshot/s**

The steps are:

1. Create a directory on your local machine with the snapshot/s you want to restore
2. Navigate to `elasticsearch.yml` file. For example, on my local machine, you can find the file here: `/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/7.8.1/libexec/config/elasticsearch.yml`
3. add the repository path: `path.repo: [PATH_TO_BACKUP_DIR]` on the `elasticsearch.yml` file. For example: `path.repo: ["/mount/backups", "/mount/longterm_backups"]`
4. save, exit, and restart elasticsearch
5. After all nodes are restarted, the following command can be used to register the shared file system repository with the name `my_fs_backup`
6. curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_fs_backup?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
   {
   "type": "fs",
   "settings": {
   "location": "PATH_TO_BACKUP_DIR", // Example: location" : "/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/elastic-backup"
   "compress": true
   }
   }'
7. Check your configuration: `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_snapshot/_all?pretty"`
8. **Restore from snapshot:**

   8.1 **Get all snapshots:** `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_fs_backup/*?pretty`

You will get this screen:
[image]

Pick the snapshot you want (In case you have more than one)

Use this command to restore:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_snapshot/BACKUP_NAME/SNAPSHOT_ID/_restore?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
       {
        "indices": "users, events",
        "ignore_unavailable": true,
        "include_global_state": true
       }
```

For example:

```
 curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_fs_backup/elastic-snapshot-2020.09.05-lwul1zb9qaorq0k9vmd5rq/_restore?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "indices": "users, events",
    "ignore_unavailable": true,
    "include_global_state": true
 }
```

**Pay attention that I imported only 2 indices** `users` and `events`

Hope it helps

More info and extended tutorials:
[Elastic website](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/modules-snapshots.html#_shared_file_system_repository), [jee-appy blogspot](https://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/11/elasticsearch-backup-and-restore.html)

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: This solution uses slightly different repository storage, but the behaviour is expected to be the same!**

I know it's a zombie question, but I currently stumbled of this, while testing restore procedure of ElasticSnapshots with Azure Repository plugin.

I created a snapshot on our old PAAS Openstack and tried restoring on a fresh Azure Elastic cluster where I tested the connectivity of Azure repositories before. I still got the "repository location" in my case:

```
{
  "type": "azure",
  "settings": {
    "container": "restore",
    "chunk_size": "32MB",
    "compress": true
  }
}
```

But restoring always got the me the missing repository exception:

```
{
 "error" : {
  "root_cause" : [
   {
    "type" : "repository_missing_exception",
    "reason" : "[restore] missing"
   }
  ],
  "type" : "repository_missing_exception",
  "reason" : "[restore] missing"
 },
 "status" : 404
}
```

Turns out another branch got deployed on my test Azure k8s cluster which removed the Azure repository plugin and with it the connectivity to the repository. Even restoring the plugin did not help fixing the `missing_repository_exception`

Carefully re-reading the docs (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/snapshots-register-repository.html) gave me this:

> You can unregister a repository using the delete snapshot repository API.
> When a repository is unregistered, Elasticsearch only removes the reference to the location where the repository is storing the snapshots. The snapshots themselves are left untouched and in place.

So what solved the `missing_repository_exception` in my case was doing a "bit scary":

```
DELETE /_snapshot/restore
```

and then recreating the snapshot location with:

```
PUT https://localhost:9200/_snapshot/restore --data '
 {
   "type": "azure",
   "settings": {
     "container": "restore",
     "chunk_size": "32MB",
     "compress": true
   }
 }'
```

Then the previously failing snapshot restore command succeded:

```
 POST https://localhost:9200/_snapshot/restore/snapshot_2020810/_restore
 {"accepted":true}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_snapshot/old_backup/snapshot_to_ubuntu?pretty=1
```

That command creates snapshot. Because you didnt create a repository on ubuntu side, you get error.

What you want is to restore so you should use `_restore` endpoint:

```
POST /_snapshot/old_backup/snapshot_to_ubuntu/_restore
```

Check:https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/modules-snapshots.html#_restore

Comment: I updated the question. That `restore` gave me the same error